# javascript onblur function not working

Tags: javascript

I can't get onblur function at second row onwards, please help me.
Here is my code.

**javascript**

```
function calc()
{
var fi = document.getElementById("one");
var se = document.getElementById("two");
var th = fi.value * 59.63;
document.getElementById("three").value=th;
} 
function addRow(){ 
//var table=document.getElementById('countTable');
var tbody=document.getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0];
var row=document.createElement('TR');
var cell1=document.createElement('TD');
var cell2=document.createElement('TD');
var cell3=document.createElement('TD');

var cell1value='';
cell1value+='One <input type="text" name="one" id="one" value="">';
var cell2value='';
cell2value+='Two <input type="text" name="two" id="two" value="">';
var cell3value='';
cell3value+='Three <input type="text" name="three" id="three" value="">';

cell1.innerHTML=cell1value;
cell2.innerHTML=cell2value;
cell3.innerHTML=cell3value;

row.appendChild(cell1);
row.appendChild(cell2);
row.appendChild(cell3);

tbody.appendChild(row);
//alert(table+' '+row+' ');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table name="entry" width="100%" id="countTable">
<TBODY>
<tr>
<td>One 
<input type="text" name="one" id="one" value="" onBlur="calc();">
</td>
<td>Two
<input type="text" name="two" id="two" value="" onBlur="calc();">
</td>
<td>Three
<input type="text" name="three" id="three" value="">
</td>
</tr>
</TBODY>
</table>

<input type="button" name="add" value="Add" onClick="addRow();">
```

Comment: Where do you make use of the `onBlur` event in any other row?

Answer (score 5):

Notice the `input` elements in your initial row:

```
<input type="text" name="one" id="one" value="" onBlur="calc();">
```

And the input elements in your subsequent rows:

```
<input type="text" name="one" id="one" value="">
```

There's a key difference between them which prevents the subsequent rows from making use of the `onBlur` event.  In order to respond to the event, just like in the first row, you need to actually *attach a handler* for that event.  Something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="one" id="one" value="" onBlur="calc();">
```

Note, however, that your code has other problems.  Namely:

- You're re-using `id` values, so the behavior or anything using those `id`s (such as your `calc` function) will be undefined.  `id`s need to be unique throughout the document.
- You're re-using `name` values.  While allowed, this could lead to unintended side-effects when you try to use the values posted by this form.  Later elements may obscure the values from earlier elements.